# Converter codigo C pra assembly MIPS?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, mips, cross-compiler

Como eu posso gerar o código Assembly correspondente ao código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define LINHA  4
#define COLUNA 5

int tab [LINHA][COLUNA] = {
    2016,2012,2008,2004,2000,
    1916,1911,1908,1904,1900,
    1861,1857,1852,1846,1844,
    1728,1727,1726,1725,1723};

int cnt = 0;

int resultado[COLUNA] = {0,0,0,0,0};


int main() {
  int l, i, tmp; 

  do{
      printf("Qual linha deseja verificar?");
        scanf("%d", &l);
  }while(l >= LINHA);

  for(i = 0; i < COLUNA; i++){
        tmp = f_bissexto(l, i);  # esse metodo consegui fzer f_bissexto
        if(tmp){
            resultado[cnt] = tmp; 
            cnt++;          
        }
    }

    imprimir();

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Acho que não é o objetivo do site fazer um novo código, ou seja fazer tudo para você. Precisaria de uma pergunta específica em algum ponto que está com problema. Eu não perderia tempo com isto. Dá um trabalho monstro fazer um código melhor do que o compilador C produzirá, especialmente se tentar melhor este código em C. O ganho neste tipo de código não justifica a conversão.

Comment: Utilize esta opção de formatação de código quando for código que pode ser executado no frontend como Javascript, HTML, CSS e assim por diante. Não use para código backend, como C que depende de um compilador, para código backend você pode usar o `{ }` ou selecionar o código e apertar as teclas `ctrl+k`. [Veja como formatar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Maniero Achei a pergunta bastante relevante. Acho que com as devidas TAGs a pergunta fique mais clara.

Comment: Também achei a pergunta boa ja que existem ferramentas para isso.

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver em uma máquina com arquitetura `MIPS` nativa, você pode usar o compilador `GCC` passando o argumento `-S` para que ele gere o código em `assembly` equivalente ao programa escrito em C, por exemplo:

```
$ gcc -S bissexto.c -o bissexto.asm
```

Poreḿ, se você não estiver em uma arquitetura `MIPS`, você vai precisar de um `cross-compiler`.

Nesse caso, sugiro o `Codescape MIPS SDK` que pode ser obtido [aqui](https://community.imgtec.com/developers/mips/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/).

Uma vez com o `Codescape MIPS SDK` instalado:

```
$ pwd
/opt/imgtec/Toolchains/mips-mti-linux-gnu/2016.05-03/bin

$ ls -al
total 136060
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root     4096 Oct  3 20:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 9 root root     4096 Oct  3 20:46 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5151584 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-addr2line
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5320040 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7876560 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-as
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3351704 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-c++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5106592 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-c++filt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3347032 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   100104 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-elfedit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3351704 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-g++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3343240 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3343240 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc-4.9.2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   145264 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   145056 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   145064 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2313536 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcov
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 30093240 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3352168 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gfortran
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5681544 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-gprof
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7715008 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-ld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7715008 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-ld.bfd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5188192 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-nm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6138528 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-objcopy
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7251864 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-objdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5320040 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1345744 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-readelf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5142248 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-size
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5141808 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-strings
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6138584 Jun 26  2016 mips-mti-linux-gnu-strip
```

Você pode utilizar o compilador `mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc` para gerar o código `assembly` equivalente ao programa em C:

```
$ ./mips-mti-linux-gnu-gcc -S bissexto.c -o bissexto.asm
```

**bissexto.asm:**

```
    .file   1 "bissexto.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .nan    legacy
    .module fp=xx
    .module nooddspreg
    .abicalls
    .option pic0
    .globl  tab
    .data
    .align  2
    .type   tab, @object
    .size   tab, 80
tab:
    .word   2016
    .word   2012
    .word   2008
    .word   2004
    .word   2000
    .word   1916
    .word   1911
    .word   1908
    .word   1904
    .word   1900
    .word   1861
    .word   1857
    .word   1852
    .word   1846
    .word   1844
    .word   1728
    .word   1727
    .word   1726
    .word   1725
    .word   1723
    .globl  cnt
    .section    .bss,"aw",@nobits
    .align  2
    .type   cnt, @object
    .size   cnt, 4
cnt:
    .space  4
    .globl  resultado
    .align  2
    .type   resultado, @object
    .size   resultado, 20
resultado:
    .space  20
    .rdata
    .align  2
$LC0:
    .ascii  "Qual linha deseja verificar?\000"
    .align  2
$LC1:
    .ascii  "%d\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .set    nomicromips
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $fp,48,$31      # vars= 16, regs= 2/0, args= 16, gp= 8
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-48
    sw  $31,44($sp)
    sw  $fp,40($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
$L2:
    lui $2,%hi($LC0)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC0)
    jal printf
    nop

    addiu   $3,$fp,32
    lui $2,%hi($LC1)
    addiu   $4,$2,%lo($LC1)
    move    $5,$3
    jal __isoc99_scanf
    nop

    lw  $2,32($fp)
    slt $2,$2,4
    beq $2,$0,$L2
    nop

    sw  $0,24($fp)
    b   $L3
    nop

$L5:
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    move    $4,$2
    lw  $5,24($fp)
    jal f_bissexto
    nop

    sw  $2,28($fp)
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    beq $2,$0,$L4
    nop

    lui $2,%hi(cnt)
    lw  $3,%lo(cnt)($2)
    lui $2,%hi(resultado)
    sll $3,$3,2
    addiu   $2,$2,%lo(resultado)
    addu    $2,$3,$2
    lw  $3,28($fp)
    sw  $3,0($2)
    lui $2,%hi(cnt)
    lw  $2,%lo(cnt)($2)
    addiu   $3,$2,1
    lui $2,%hi(cnt)
    sw  $3,%lo(cnt)($2)
$L4:
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,24($fp)
$L3:
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    slt $2,$2,5
    bne $2,$0,$L5
    nop

    jal imprimir
    nop

    move    $2,$0
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $31,44($sp)
    lw  $fp,40($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,48
    jr  $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Codescape GNU Tools 2016.05-03 for MIPS MTI Linux) 4.9.2"
```

Comment: Queria saber de uma forma mais didática porque a forma como é gerada pelo compilador fica difícil de entender pra mim que estou aprendendo... Mas valeu pela ideia!

Comment: Forma mais didatica? Em Assembly nao existe forma mais didatica, é complicado de enteder mesmo. Por isso se tornou uma linguagem obsoleta.

Comment: Muito interessante. Teria como fazer o caminho inverso? De Assembly para C?

Comment: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm caminho inverso

Comment: @gfleck: De `assembly` para `C` é uma outra história... Mas é possível desmontar um binário para seu código em `assembly` equivalente por meio do utilitário `objdump`. Por exemplo: `$objdump -d -Mintel /usr/bin/ls`